# Lifecycle.addObserverUntilDestroy extension stopped working with AndroidX

Tags: android, kotlin, android-lifecycle, androidx, kotlin-extension

I've been using following Kotlin extension to add my lifecycle observers:

```
fun Lifecycle.addObserverUntilDestroy(observer: LifecycleObserver) {
    addObserver(observer)

    addObserver(object : LifecycleObserver {
        @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY)
        fun onDestroy() {
            removeObserver(this)
            removeObserver(observer)
        }
    })
}
```

The idea was to automatically remove the observer when the Lifecycle is being destroyed.

So I can call it in Activity's onPostCreate (in this case a Java code but it is the same when calling from Kotlin):

```
ArchitectureComponentExtensions.addObserverUntilDestroy(getLifecycle(), myViewModel);
```

And have this code in my ViewModel (a custom one, not the on from Architecture Components):

```
@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY)
public void onViewDestroyed() {
    // This is not being called anymore
}
```

But this stopped working after migrating from:

```
import android.arch.lifecycle.Lifecycle
import android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleObserver
import android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner
import android.arch.lifecycle.OnLifecycleEvent
```

to:

```
import androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle
import androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleObserver
import androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner
import androidx.lifecycle.OnLifecycleEvent
```

Any ideas why this is not working anymore?